# Is it possible disable button 'Add to cart' when point insufficient

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to ask everyone to know about WooCommerce WordPress. I have a page for list product WooCommerce, in there have information like title and price and button "Add to cart" when the cursor hovers to the product. I want to disable or hide the button when my point is insufficient for the product. Is it possible to do that? I am using plugin GamiPress - WooCommerce Points Gateway for payment with points

Above this example for a product (100 points)

[image]

Above this my current point (0 point)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [remove_action()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_action/) to remove add to cart in certain conditions.

```
$point = 0;
if($point == 0){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart');
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the disabled attribute on the button if points are insufficient for the product. For example, you can get the total points in the var pints and if the points are less than 100 you add disable attribute to the button.

```
var point;
if(point<100 ){
$('.add-to-cart').attr('disabled');


}
```